# How to repeat a function and handler untill the user gives a valid reply to telegram bot?

Tags: python, telegram, chatbot, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I just got into learning to build telegram bot using telegram-bot-api-python module. I made three functions one `/start` command function to start converstaion and this function asks for user phone number and send it to other handler or function called `reply_with_number` where the reply of user will be vaidated using `if` `else` statements and if the user reply is valid then he will be sent to another handler or function called `ask_link` this is the last one and he will reply me with a link. Everything is fine but when the user enters some string like "`thisstring`" instead of phone number then the function `reply_with_number` should keep running or keep asking for valid phone number untill he types valid one. But mine is just getting out of that `reply_with_number` and running the next `ask_link` handler without waiting for reply. How can solve this problem ?
**My code:**

```
import time
from telegram import MessageEntity,Bot
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, ConversationHandler
from telegram import KeyboardButton, ReplyKeyboardMarkup, ReplyKeyboardRemove

updater = Updater(token=token, use_context=True)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

def start(update, context):
    username = update.message.from_user.first_name
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,
                             text=f"Hello {username}, Welcome to my bot!")
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,
                             text='May i know your phone no ?')

def reply_with_number(update, context):
        if update.message.text and len(update.message.text) <= 13:
            try:
                if update.message.text[0:3] == '+91':
                    phone_number = int(update.message.text[3:])
                elif update.message.text[0:2] == '91':
                    phone_number = int(update.message.text[2:])
                elif update.message.text[0] == '0':
                    phone_number = int(update.message.text[1:])
                else:
                    phone_number = int(update.message.text)
                    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,
                                             text='Looks good!',
                                             reply_markup=reply_markup)
            except Exception as e:
                update.message.reply_text('Please enter phone number not strings!')

def ask_link(update, context):
    link = update.message.text
    neat_url = strip(link)
    if neat_url != None:
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,
                                 text='Link looks good')
    elif neat_url == None:
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,
                                 text='Its invalid!')


start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start)
dispatcher.add_handler(start_handler)

reply_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.contact | Filters.text, reply_with_number)
dispatcher.add_handler(reply_handler)

ask_for_link = MessageHandler(Filters.text, ask_link)
dispatcher.add_handler(ask_for_link)

updater.start_polling()
```

Screenshot of problem:
[image]

Comment: If you want to keep running `reply_with_number`, until the user enters valid input, you should probably add a loop in `reply_with_number`. The loop's condition should check whether the user entered valid input; and keep repeating if the input was not valid.

Comment: Sure i will try this and let you know. Thank you for helping me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `ConversationHandler` for this situation, and just return the proper message for the user to try again and the correct return so the bot knows the user still in the same step on the conversation handler, example:

```
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, ConversationHandler


FIRST_STEP, SECOND_STEP = range(2)

conversation_handler = ConversationHandler(
    entry_points=[CommandHandler('start', start)],
    states={
        FIRST_STEP: [MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, first_step)],
        SECOND_STEP: [MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, second_step)],
    },
    fallbacks=[CommandHandler('cancel', cancel)]
)

def start(bot, update):
    bot.send_message(
        chat_id=update.message.chat_id, 
        text='2 + 2 = ?', 
        parse_mode='markdown')
    return FIRST_STEP

def cancel(bot, update):
    bot.send_message(
        chat_id=update.message.chat_id, 
        text='2 + 2 = ?')
    return ConversationHandler.END

def first_step(bot, update):
    if update.message.text != '4':
        bot.send_message(
            chat_id=update.message.chat_id, 
            text='Sorry try again to enter a valid input.')
        bot.send_message(
            chat_id=update.message.chat_id, 
            text='2 + 2 = ?')
        return FIRST_STEP
    else:
        bot.send_message(
            chat_id=update.message.chat_id, 
            text='The answer is right, you are in the next step')
        return SECOND_STEP

def second_step(bot, update):
    bot.send_message(
        chat_id=update.message.chat_id, 
        text='Correct answer', 
        parse_mode='markdown')
    return ConversationHandler.END
```

Reference docs:
https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.conversationhandler.html?highlight=ConversationHandler